# type of namespace name Masterdetailpage does not exist in the namespace xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, mobile

Fairly straight forward new cross platform App PCL project (Portable Class library) .

Inside my portable project I have a simple MasterDetailPage xaml file which shows no errors. No files have errors, everything looks perfect and ready to run.

When i try and run i have 2 errors:

**Error 1.**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'ABCRM, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
>   File name: 'ABCRM.dll'
>      at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
>      at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName, ReaderParameters parameters)
>      at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName)
>      at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.GetAssembly(String fileName)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res, ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() ABCRM.Android

**Error 2.**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'MasterDetailPAge' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  ABCRM   C:\dev\xamarin\ABCRM\ABCRM\ABCRM\obj\Debug\ABCRM.MainPage.xaml.g.cs 15  Active

I attach a snapshot as well with the error.

Can someone give me a hand because I am going crazy searching the web but no actual answers found.

[Picture of error I get when building the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdlAz.jpg)

Comment: Can you tell us wich Xamarin version do you use?

Comment: You talk about MasterDetailPage, your error talk about MasterDetailPAge. There is a difference between the two name, check this.

Comment: Seuleuzeuh this is embarrassing but thank you. That was the issue. My xaml contained  MasterDetailPAge instead of MasterDetailPage.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Seuleuzeuh is : My xaml contained MasterDetailPAge instead of MasterDetailPage

Thank you